# Array path from variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, eval, dynamic-arrays

So I wrote a class that can parse XML documents and create SQL queries from it to update or insert new rows depending on the settings.

Because the script has to work with any amount of nested blocks, the array that I'm putting all the values in has its path dynamically created much like the following example:

```
$path = array('field1','field2');
$path = "['".implode("']['",$path)."']";

eval("\$array".$path."['value'] = 'test';");
```

Basically `$path` contains an array that shows how deep in the array we currently are, if `$path` contains for instance the values `main_table` and `field` I want set `$array['main_table']['field']['value']` to `'test'`

As you can see I am currently using eval to do this, and this works fine. I am just wondering if there is a way to do this without using eval.

Something like
`$array{$path}['value'] = 'test';` but then something that actually works.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The reason I'm looking for an alternative is because I think eval is bad practice.

**SECOND EDIT**

Changed actual code to dummy code because it was causing a lot of misunderstandings.

Comment: yeah, well. This looks a lot like you are doing it wrong. Can you please show the input XML and the output you want to achieve. You might be able to get this working with Iterators.

Comment: oh dear god... Variable of variables are wrong, but this is just.. ahhhh <head bursts> (no offense, just joking)

Comment: This is only a small part of the entire system, and it works perfectly. The reason I do it like this is because you need to be able to set a table, fieldname and multiple other options - per xml block - defining what needs to happen to the data. Nothing is going 'wrong', except me not wanting to use eval.

Comment: [This thing](https://github.com/robik/APath) could be usefull :)

Comment: @Kokos : I edited my comment to add "no offense", because I was just joking. Regarding your problem can't you start by using functions ? Maybe use **recursion** to iterate through your data ? I guess it's not easy to solve, but it can be i'm sure.

Comment: If this is only a snippet of the entire system, and your entire system of parsing XML into SQL is so long it cannot be posted here, you are definetly doing it wrong. `eval`? Really? You are taking the hard road man.

Comment: A lot of things that work perfectly are wrong nonetheless. A surgeon can operate you with a spoon if he sharpens that, but that doesnt make it any less wrong. So instead of being offended, why not just do as asked and provide the input and desired output. After all, you are the one who asked and wants an alternative to that abomination above, not us ;)

Comment: @Gordon I am not offended, I am open to any sort of help, what I am saying is that the ouput already is as desired. I am just looking for an alternative to eval. I have multiple reasons for building the rest of the system the way I did (which could likely be wrong), but it's of no importance to the question.

Comment: @Kevin the system is about 300 lines long, the reason that might be a bit large is because it requires a lot if settings from the user to make sure everything gets handled properly (some fields are for the WHERE clause and some fields need to be updated, also some need to be inserted and this all works with children blocks going in different tables etc etc), if you want I could post the code but I'm pretty sure it has no relevance to my question.

Comment: I can post a million reasons to why I do something too. However, when I need help, I'm will to use other minds to find my answers instead of getting stuck on one singular piece of the whole. Get your `eval` answer here, then I challenge you to post a question asking for PHP code to produce the output you want from the input you are given.

Comment: Kevin, what is the problem? All im asking for here is an alternative to the way i was using eval - because i think its wrong - and people start calling my code an abomination, downrating my question as well as making assumptions about the rest of my program. I love constructive criticism because it helps me become a better programmer. However, unrelated, uncalled-for criticism that leads multiple people away from the point does nothing more than cause useless arguments.

Comment: The problem is that it's not only the call to `eval` that's bad practise, but the entire code snippet you show. Instead of writing down the code that fills the array, you are writing down *the code that writes the code* to fill the array when it's evaluated. Transforming an XML file to SQL queries doesnt sound too complicated. And that's why people are telling you that you are likely doing it wrong and ask for additional information (so they can provide alternative approaches). Yet, you insist it's just the eval that's wrong and everything else is fine.

Comment: My excuses if my choice of words (working 'perfectly') appeared to some of you as me being cocky, I had no such intention. I only meant to say it's not worthwhile for me to adjust my entire program when it's working in every way I intend it to and I feel like it is programmed well enough.

Comment: The only thing I was showing was the eval part of my function, and everything related to it, and I - even in my original post - admitted to it being wrong. I think this is all just a big miscommunication.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have to agree the way I am building `$path` isn't right. You are correct in pointing me to this, the combination of you first talking about my input and output and then about the 'abomination' above lead me to think you were making assumptions about the rest of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
/**
 * Sets an element of a multidimensional array from an array containing
 * the keys for each dimension.
 * 
 * @param array &$array The array to manipulate
 * @param array $path An array containing keys for each dimension
 * @param mixed $value The value that is assigned to the element
 */
function set_recursive(&$array, $path, $value)
{
  $key = array_shift($path);
  if (empty($path)) {
    $array[$key] = $value;
  } else {
    if (!isset($array[$key]) || !is_array($array[$key])) {
      $array[$key] = array();
    }
    set_recursive($array[$key], $path, $value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This would definitely work, however I was hoping for a shorthand that would allow me to do this as quick as with eval.

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend replacing `isset` with `array_key_exists`, since `isset` will return `false`, if key is set as `null`

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the whole counter business with the array append operator:

```
$some_array[] = 1; // pushes '1' onto the end of the array
```

As for the whole path business, I'm assuming that's basically an oddball representation of an xpath-like route through your xml document... any reason you can't simply use that string as an array key itself?

```
$this->BLOCKS['/path/to/the/node/you're/working/on][] = array('name' => $name, 'target' => $target);
```

Comment: I don't think the array append operator works if I want to do two in a row, `$some_array[]['name'] = 'test'` then `$some_array[]['target'] = 'test'` will leave me with `$some_array[0]['name'] = 'test'` and `$some_array[1]['target'] = 'target'`, or can this be bypassed by doing something with `current()`?

Comment: @Kokos: no, it'd create a new one each time. but if you do it like I am, by assign a new array you can append all your elements at the same time.

Comment: The `= array()` is definitely something I will start using, I had been looking previously for a PHP array shorthand much like `= ['field'=>'value']` in Actionscript, I never thought of using the normal syntax in cases like this. The "path business" is simply imploding an array with `][`, resulting in `field][field][field`, and then after prefixing `[` and suffixing `]` I throw this into eval to make an array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a foreach with [variable variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
// assuming a base called $array, and the path as in your example:
$path = array('field1','field2');

$$path = $array;
foreach ($path as $v) $$path = $$path[$v];
$$path['value'] = 'test';
```

Short, simple, and much better than eval.

Comment: how is this supposed to work, if `$$path = $array;` implies array to string conversion?