# PHP, Best way of setting a value in a multi-dimensional array when the pathway is dynamic?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**Solution Found:** [Dynamic array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508352/dynamic-array-keys/7508421#7508421)

---

I have a multi dimensional dynamic array, the format of which varies. for example.

`$data = array('blah1'=>array('blah2'=>array('hello'=>'world')));`

I then have a dynamic pathway as a string.

`$pathway = 'blah1/blah2/hellow';`

The pathway is broken up into it's component parts, for simplicities' sake:

`$pathway_parts = explode('/', $pathway);`

My problem arises from wanting to set the value of 'hello'. The way I currently do it is via eval, but I want to illiminate this evil partly because of the php Suhosin hardening breaking the app, but also because I don't believe this is the best way.

`eval('$data["'.implode('"]["', $pathway_parts).'"] = $value;');`

$data must always return the full array because further down the array it is serialised and stored. What would the best way to transverse the array to set the value without the use of eval?

Comment: I can't think of a good way to do this without eval, given the multidimensional array is dynamic and might have different amount of depth levels each call.
Are you sure this is the best implementation for your problem?

Comment: I am thinking drill down to the lowest level and then get a pointer to reference that value and change it I am not to familiar with pointers in php and I am kinda drawing a blank to drill down... But I think it would work..

Comment: @LaurenceBurke - exactly. the solution i found (see top of post) does exactly that.

Comment: YAY for me didnt even realize I was on the right track.... I R SMRT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using references to gradually work your way to referencing that value.

```
$data = array('blah1'=>array('blah2'=>array('hello'=>'world')));
$pathway = 'blah1/blah2/hello';
$pathway_parts = explode('/', $pathway);
$ref = &$data;

foreach ($pathway_parts as $part)
{
   // Possibly check if $ref[$part] is set before doing this.
   $ref = &$ref[$part];
}

$ref = 'value';

var_export($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't sound like the best structure, but something like this might work:

```
//$data = array('blah1'=>array('blah2'=>array('hello'=>'world')));
$pathway = 'blah1/blah2/hellow';
$pathway_parts = explode('/', $pathway);
$value = 'some value';

$data = $value;
while($path = array_pop($pathway_parts)){
    $data = array($path=>$data);
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,true).'</pre>';
```

Other than that, you might be able to build a json string and use json_decode on it. json_decode doesn't execute code.

Comment: Thanks but no, that reads the value from the array and has nothing to do with setting the value.

Comment: oops, thought you meant to get the value.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, I believe that still doesn't work. I found a solution and posted it in an edit of the original question. You need to reference the original array when looping over the keys

Comment: @buggedcom damn, array_pop() should be on the pathway parts. just a mistake on my part. This should work though.