# Php dynamic variable names

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable which holds an assoc array:

```
$arr = [
    'key' => [
        'sub' => 'Hello'
    ]
];
```

I have also another varibale which is a string matching the sub key:

```
$str = (string) '["key"]["sub"]';
```

How can I make $arr var to echo the sub key in the $str variable dynamicaly? 
Maybe in this direction.

```
echo $arr . ${$str};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data

Comment: I can not grasp why you would have a $str like that ...

Comment: I don't, I am just curious and can't seem to make it work.

Comment: here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/php-dynamic-variables.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.  If you have a specific requirement and you think this is the way then please ask a more general question that does not presuppose this method. But since you're just curious:

```
eval('echo $arr'.$str.';');
```