# PHP paradoxical (weird) behavior. Sending array to function by reference

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

Could someone explain me, why this code works properly without crashing initial array structure?

```
function setArrayValueByPath($path, $value, &$array)
{
    foreach ($path as $p) {
        $array = &$array[$p];
    }
    $array = $value;
    return true;
}

$array = [
    'a' => 'v1',
    'b' => 'v2',
];
setArrayValueByPath(['hello', 'world'], '!!!', $array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I run the code, I see:

```
Array
(
    [a] => v1
    [b] => v2
    [hello] => Array
        (
            [world] => !!!
        )

)
```

Due to the line in function:

```
$array = $value;
```

it should replace $array value, but it does not happen.

My function is based on code snippets are given here: [Using a string path to set nested array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine this one step at a time.

The parameter `$array` is a *local variable* within the function which contains a reference to some external array being passed in.

```
foreach ($path as $p) {
```

This iterates over `['hello', 'world']`

```
    $array = &$array[$p];
```

Take the original array, and "index" it with `$p` (i.e. [hello]). This does not currently exist so it is added to the original array.  Then take a reference to that new member and save it in the *local variable* `$array`.  I.e. you just created a new member of the original array, and the local variable `$array` *no longer points to the original external array*.

On the second iteration, take the variable currently pointed to by `$array` (see just above) and index it with `$p` (`world`). This does not exist, so create it.

```
}
```

At this point `$array` points to the member `{original array}[hello][world]`.  I use the syntax `{original array}` here because you no longer have a reference to it, only a reference to an array two levels nested within it.

```
$array = $value;
```

This sets the value of that member to `!!!`, giving exactly the data structure you see.

Comment: Despite on SO asks to avoid "thanks" in the comments, I still thank you here, Sir.
Well.. Lookks clear now, but am I correct it is much better to use differently named variables to make code more understandable?