# Use array values as new multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Edit (after downvote): There is a similar question here > [Using a string path to set nested array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data)
However I didn't find that question when searching for an answer due to the way it's worded, and I'm sure this will happen for other people, so this question may act as a useful gateway to that question and it's answers.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't think how to do this: I have an array containing one or more items:

```
array('value1', 'value2');
```

I need to use these values as the keys in a multidimensional array :

```
array['value1']['value2'] = 'somevalue';
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are your values Integers or could they be Strings or objects of any kind?

Comment: all values in the initial array are strings

Comment: And where do you get the 'somevalue' from?

Comment: That's a value in the same object that also contains the first array as a property

Comment: You are also going to run into issues if those values aren't unique.

Comment: Yeah, I've just realised that

Comment: This isn't the same as the linked to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nice recursion here:

```
function nestArray($items, $value) {
    return $items ?
        array($items[0] => nestArray(array_slice($items, 1), $value))
        : $value;
}

$array = array('value1', 'value2');
print_r(nestArray($array, 'somevalue'));
```