# PHP use string as array key pattern

Tags: php

I need a string to use it for a array pattern to find a value by this.
for example

```
$test = ['test','test2' => ['test3','test4' => ['test5']]];
$pattern = "['test2']['test4']"
$response = $test{$pattern} <- search
```

give it a way to solve this ?

Comment: no idea what your actully trying to do here

Comment: i want in this case as reponse test5 by this pattern

Comment: Does it really need to be a pattern? Could you do `$pattern = ['test2', 'test4']`?

Comment: If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names

Comment: ah, penny drops, i would bet there is going to be a better approach however.

Comment: Ugly way: `$response = eval('$test' . $pattern);`

Comment: this way dont work

Comment: @Barmar I think that the world would be best off if we all tried our best to pretend that `eval()` does not exist.

Comment: @Sammitch I agree. I provided a link to something that would be a more useful starting point.

Comment: i found a way with eval

Comment: now look what youve done @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Based on another question: [Using a string path to set nested array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data)

```
function GetValueFromPattern($arr, $pattern) {
    $exploded = explode(".",$pattern);

    $temp = $arr;
    foreach($exploded as $key) {
        if(key_exists($key, $temp)) {
            $temp = $temp[$key];
        } else {
            return ["status" => false];
        }
    }
    return ["status" => true, "response" => $temp];
}

$test = ['test','test2' => ['test3'=>"a",'test4' => ['test5']]];
$pattern = "test2.test3";
$response = GetValueFromPattern($test, $pattern);
if ($response["status"]) {
    echo $response["response"];
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Comment: You'd definitely want to toss in `if(key_exists($key, $temp);) {} else {/* error stuff */}`

Comment: Note that you only need to use references if you want to assign to the result. Otherwise you can use normal assignment.

Comment: Yeah you definitely don't want to return a reference from a "getter" and accidentally modify the array later.

Comment: You are right, my mistakes. The problems fixed, and I inserted the algorithm into a new function that will handle the procedure.