# make nested array base of character who divide by dot

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

i want array nested base of digit/character who divide by dot

i already tried any method what i know but the result not show as i want

this is example what i want (base of this 3, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3) 
nested array base number of character.

**My current array:**

```
array (
82 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '83',
    'KodeRekening' => '3',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'PEMBIAYAAN',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
83 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '84',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Penerimaan Pembiayaan ',
    'Anggaran' => '99475000',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
84 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '85',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1.1',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'SILPA ',
    'Anggaran' => '99475000',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
85 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '86',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1.2',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Pencairan Dana Cadangan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
86 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '87',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1.3',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Hasil Kekayaan Desa Yang dipisahkan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
87 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '88',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.2',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Pengeluaran   Pembiayaan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
88 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '89',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.2.1',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Pembentukan Dana Cadangan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
89 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '90',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.2.2',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Penyertaan Modal Desa ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
```

**Required Output:**

```
  {
        "APBKID": "1404",
        "KodeRekening": "3",
        "LevelRekening": "",
        "KodeRekeningInduk": "",
        "Uraian": "PEMBIAYAAN",
        "Anggaran": "",
        "Keterangan": "",
        "TahunAnggaran": "2019",
        "DanaDesa": "",
        "AlokasiDanaDesa": "",
        "KampungID": "2",
        "NamaKampung": "Aramsolki",
        "Data": [
            {
                "APBKID": "1405",
                "KodeRekening": "3.1",
                "LevelRekening": "",
                "KodeRekeningInduk": "",
                "Uraian": "Penerimaan Pembiayaan ",
                "Anggaran": "99475000",
                "Keterangan": "",
                "TahunAnggaran": "2019",
                "DanaDesa": "",
                "AlokasiDanaDesa": "",
                "KampungID": "2",
                "NamaKampung": "Aramsolki",
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "APBKID": "1406",
                        "KodeRekening": "3.1.1",
                        "LevelRekening": "",
                        "KodeRekeningInduk": "",
                        "Uraian": "SILPA ",
                        "Anggaran": "99475000",
                        "Keterangan": "",
                        "TahunAnggaran": "2019",
                        "DanaDesa": "",
                        "AlokasiDanaDesa": "",
                        "KampungID": "2",
                        "NamaKampung": "Aramsolki"

                    },
                    {
                        "APBKID": "1407",
                        "KodeRekening": "3.1.2",
                        "LevelRekening": "",
                        "KodeRekeningInduk": "",
                        "Uraian": "Pencairan Dana Cadangan ",
                        "Anggaran": "",
                        "Keterangan": "",
                        "TahunAnggaran": "2019",
                        "DanaDesa": "",
                        "AlokasiDanaDesa": "",
                        "KampungID": "2",
                        "NamaKampung": "Aramsolki"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: 3 things: Sample input, Sample output and where are you stuck?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @vivek_23 that is example. i cant make it. can you help me make it using php?

Comment: @kerbholz i want make like that json use php

Comment: make nested array base of this character 3, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3 and result like above

Comment: Make that Json from what? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Right now your question is unclear (at least for me)

Comment: @kerbholz sorry if my question unclear. the point of my question i want make nested array base of character divede by dot (3, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3). so 3 as parent array. 3.1 child of 3. 3.1.1 child of 3.1.

Comment: You probably want to work with an approach such as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/

Comment: @HendriSildrian manually make the output and show it in your post.

Comment: @vivek_23 sorry i forgot write the real array. this real array https://pastebin.com/r8dzqjp3
i want this array nested and show like json data above

Comment: @HendriSildrian can you do a `var_export()` of your array and show us what you tried/your approach?

Comment: @vivek_23 this is result of var_export(). https://pastebin.com/Ty0Ln8kq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky problem as we need to deal with references here(at least in my solution). So, we would go step by step.

**Sort the data:**

```
<?php 

// assume your array name is $arr 

usort($arr,function($array1,$array2){
    $version_1 = explode(".",$array1['KodeRekening']);
    $version_2 = explode(".",$array2['KodeRekening']);

    $size_1 = count($version_1);
    $size_2 = count($version_2);

    $min_size = min($size_1,$size_2);

    for($i=0;$i<$min_size;++$i){
        if(intval($version_1[$i]) < intval($version_2[$i])){
            return -1;
        }else if(intval($version_1[$i]) > intval($version_2[$i])){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return $size_1 - $size_2;
});
```

In the above code, we sort your array data in a manner that always parent version would come before child version. For example: `3.1` would come before `3.1.1` etc.

**Get last Index:**

```
function lastIndex($arr){
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    return end($keys);
}
```

We will use the above function to get last element of the array in the below code. It's better to make it a function as we would be reusing it more than once.

**Actual computation:**

```
<?php

$set = [];
$result = [];

foreach($arr as $curr){
    $version = $curr['KodeRekening'];
    $parent_version = implode(".",array_slice(explode(".",$version),0,-1));

    if(isset($set[$parent_version])){
        $parent_element = &$set[$parent_version];
        if(!isset($parent_element['data'])) $parent_element['data'] = [];
        $parent_element['data'][] = $curr;
        $set[$version] = &$parent_element['data'][lastIndex($parent_element['data'])];
    }else{
        $result[] = $curr;
        $set[$version] = &$result[lastIndex($result)];  
    }
}
```

In the above code:

- We have 2 arrays `$set` and `$result`. We will use `$set` to get the parent array quickly and we will use `$result` to store the final output.
- Now, for each version, we compute a parent version from your key `KodeRekening`. The way we do that is just to remove the last dot (`.`) and everything after it.
- Once we get the parent version, we check to see if `parent_version` exists in our `$set`. If no, we add it to `$result` as is and store the `current_version` in `$set`.
  If `yes`, we get the `parent_version` from our `$set` and add it in it's `data` key. We also save `current_version` in `$set` accordingly.
- We use references `&` in our code. This means that we edit the same copy of array present in `$result`. This means that any modification we do, such as `$parent_element['data'][] = $curr;` will automatically reflect in `$result` since we are passing variables by references here, so we are editing the same copy as written in lines `$set[$version] = &$parent_element['data'][lastIndex($parent_element['data'])];` and `$set[$version] = &$result[lastIndex($result)];`.

**Full Code:**

```
<?php

$arr = array (
82 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '83',
    'KodeRekening' => '3',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'PEMBIAYAAN',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
83 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '84',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Penerimaan Pembiayaan ',
    'Anggaran' => '99475000',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
84 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '85',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1.1',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'SILPA ',
    'Anggaran' => '99475000',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
85 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '86',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1.2',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Pencairan Dana Cadangan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
86 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '87',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.1.3',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Hasil Kekayaan Desa Yang dipisahkan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
87 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '88',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.2',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Pengeluaran   Pembiayaan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
88 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '89',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.2.1',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Pembentukan Dana Cadangan ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  ),
89 => 
  array (
    'APBKID' => '90',
    'KodeRekening' => '3.2.2',
    'LevelRekening' => NULL,
    'KodeRekeningInduk' => NULL,
    'Uraian' => 'Penyertaan Modal Desa ',
    'Anggaran' => '0',
    'Keterangan' => NULL,
    'TahunAnggaran' => '2019',
    'KampungID' => '1',
    'DanaDesa' => NULL,
    'AlokasiDanaDesa' => NULL,
    'CreatedAt' => '2019-08-10 18: 20: 36',
    'CreatedBy' => '1',
    'UpdatedAt' => '2019-09-06 12: 31: 21',
    'UpdatedBy' => '1',
    'Deleted' => '0',
    'DistrikID' => '1',
    'NamaKampung' => 'Amungun',
    'KepalaKampung' => 'Joni Niwilingame',
    'FotoKepalaKampung' => '',
    'KodeRegisterKampung' => '91.09.02',
    'GambarKampung' => 'splash.jpg',
    'ProfilKampung' => '<p><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span><br></p>',
  )
);


usort($arr,function($array1,$array2){
    $version_1 = explode(".",$array1['KodeRekening']);
    $version_2 = explode(".",$array2['KodeRekening']);

    $size_1 = count($version_1);
    $size_2 = count($version_2);

    $min_size = min($size_1,$size_2);

    for($i=0;$i<$min_size;++$i){
        if(intval($version_1[$i]) < intval($version_2[$i])){
            return -1;
        }else if(intval($version_1[$i]) > intval($version_2[$i])){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return $size_1 - $size_2;
});

$set = [];
$result = [];

foreach($arr as $curr){
    $version = $curr['KodeRekening'];
    $parent_version = implode(".",array_slice(explode(".",$version),0,-1));

    if(isset($set[$parent_version])){
        $parent_element = &$set[$parent_version];
        if(!isset($parent_element['data'])) $parent_element['data'] = [];
        $parent_element['data'][] = $curr;
        $set[$version] = &$parent_element['data'][lastIndex($parent_element['data'])];
    }else{
        $result[] = $curr;
        $set[$version] = &$result[lastIndex($result)];  
    }
}


function lastIndex($arr){
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    return end($keys);
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/U4ssp