# Updating PHP array with path and value variables

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$animals['dogs']['lassie']['legs'] = 4
```

Given the variables

```
$path  = "['dogs']['lassie']['legs']";
$value = 3;
```

How do I update the $animals array so that

```
$animals['dogs']['lassie']['legs'] = 3;
```

My best guess of

```
$arr = 'animals'.$path;
${$arr} = $value;
```

didn't work.

I have read that it can be done using eval() but also that it shouldn't be done using eval()!

Any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Are you fixed with the format of `$path`, something like "dogs.lassie.legs" would be easier (you could then use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data)

Comment: That would work. Thank you very much