# Update associative array through a function

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need to update a specific key of an associative array thrue a function.
Is it possible ?

IMPORTANT, in `$PATH_TAB = &$TAB_cars['car_1']['blue'];` $TAB_cars['car_1']['blue'] can be different : $TAB_cars['car_1']['type']['light'], etc.

```
$TAB_cars = [
        'car_1' => [
            'red' => '',
            'blue' => '',
            'type' => [
                   'light' => '',
                   'big' => ''
                      ]
                    ],
        'car_2' => [
            'green' => '',
            'brown' => ''
            ]
        ];


function UpdateArray($PATH_TAB_2) {
    $PATH_TAB_2 = 'TEST 2';
}


$PATH_TAB_1 = &$TAB_cars['car_1']['blue'];
UpdateArray($PATH_TAB_1);

print_r($TAB_cars);
```

Comment: You need to either `return` in your function or have it pass-by-reference

Comment: Well, try to do something like : `$newArray = UpdateArray($PATH_TAB);` with `function UpdateArray($array, $path_tab) { /* update the $path_tab in your $array */ return $array; }`

Comment: I can't understand this sentence _IMPORTANT, in $PATH_TAB = &$TAB_cars['car_1']['blue']; $TAB_cars['car_1']['blue'] can be different : "deeper" or not._

Comment: @vivek_23 I just updated the sentence. Is it clear now ? THX

Comment: `function UpdateArray(&$PATH_TAB_2)`, then this would work. Rather terrible coding though, if you’d asked me. So far from your question it is not clear, what advantage that would be supposed to have, over just going `$TAB_cars['car_1']['blue'] = 'TEST 2';` directly.

Comment: I have a slight suspicion that what you are actually trying to ask, is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data

Comment: @Jean I'm sorry to say it's still unclear.

Comment: @04FS THX for the solution. And no, I already saw this solution before... THX again

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (THX to @04FS) :

```
$TAB_cars = [
        'car_1' => [
            'red' => '',
            'blue' => '',
            'type' => [
                   'light' => '',
                   'big' => ''
                      ]
                    ],
        'car_2' => [
            'green' => '',
            'brown' => ''
            ]
        ];





function UpdateArray(&$PATH_TAB_2) {
    $PATH_TAB_2 = 'TEST 2';
}

$PATH_TAB_1 = &$TAB_cars['car_1']['blue'];
UpdateArray($PATH_TAB_1);

print_r($TAB_cars);
```