# PHP: get value from array variable (which is a string) using eval() not working

Tags: php, cookies, eval

I have a function like this:

```
function getvar() { 
  $n = func_num_args(); 
  $l = func_get_args(); 
  $t = '$_COOKIE';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
    $t .= "['".$l[$i]."']"; 
  }
  // $t would be like $_COOKIE['arg1']['arg2']['arg3']
  return eval($t); 
}
```

I also have cookie expired in 24 hours:

```
$_COOKIE['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'TEST';
```

Then I call getvar() using:

```
$test = getvar('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
echo $test; //result should be 'TEST'
```

And the result is nothing.

Comment: Terrible idea to use eval for something like this in the first place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned all the way on?

Comment: _“And the result is nothing.”_ - apart from the syntax error (enable proper PHP error reporting!) – well, what would be the result you expected from `$_COOKIE['key1']['key2']['key3']` _on its own_? If you had written _just that_ onto a line into a PHP file directly, it would not produce any output or any return value either.

Comment: @ChrisHaas
I got this error :
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /hdd/program/web/demo91/modul/admin/config.php(31) : eval()'d code on line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `array_reduce()`

```
$_COOKIE = ['key1' => [ 'key2' => [ 'key3' => 'TEST' ]]];

function getvar(...$args)
{
    return array_reduce($args, fn ($a, $k) => $a[$k], $_COOKIE);
}

print_r(getvar('key1', 'key2', 'key3'));
```

Comment: I like your code so much, so elegant and efficient. But how using this way to set value to array cookie? thanks in advance.

Comment: @FauzanSamsuri what you are asking is something irrelevant to this question. Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it really helped

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I change

```
return eval($t);
```

to

```
return eval('echo ' . $t . ';');
```

and now it works as expected.