# PHP curly brackets for xml object

Tags: php, pimcore

is there a way to get the xml value by curly brackets?

For example I want to get the value of `test->test_test` and want to archieve this with the xml object variable. The path of the value inside the xml object comes from the database.

```
$xml_path = 'test->test_test';
    
echo $xml_obj->{$xml_path};
```

Also not working:

```
$xml_path = '{test}->{test_test}';
            
echo $xml_obj->{$xml_path};
```

Here I got the following error:

```
Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed
```

Comment: I think we will need to see at least some sample data to be able to understand whats goin gon here.

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added a better example.

Comment: You might have to cast it to a string. Try echo (String) $xml_obj->{$xml_path};

Comment: Makes no differences, because this is only then for the result.

Comment: The curly bracket syntax allows you to access _one_ property by its name put inside a variable, but it does not allow you to "jump" multiple `->` in one go.

Comment: You probably want a solution similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data, only for objects instead of arrays.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I need to jumpe over multiple -> ..
I will look at the solution. Thanks.