# String to multidimensional array path

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, here is a small excerpt:

```
Array (
    [Albums] => Array (
        [A Great Big World - Is There Anybody Out There] => Array(...),
        [ATB - Contact] => Array(...),
    )
    [Pop] => Array (...)
)
```

And I have a dynamic path:

```
/albums/a_great_big_world_-_is_there_anybody_out_there
```

What would be the best way to retrieve the value of (in this example) `$arr["albums"]["A Great Big World - Is There Anybody Out There"]`?

Please note that it should be dynamic, since the nesting can go deeper than the 2 levels in this example.

**EDIT**

Here is the function I use to create a simple string for the URL:

```
function formatURL($url) {
    return preg_replace('/__+/', '_', preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/', "", strtolower(str_replace(" ", "_", $url))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(...);
$path  = '/albums/a_great_big_world_-_is_there_anybody_out_there';

$value = $array;
foreach (explode('/', trim($path, '/')) as $key) {
    if (isset($value[$key]) && is_array($value[$key])) {
        $value = $value[$key];
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Path $path is invalid");
    }
}

echo $value;
```

Comment: This loop works, but the child in my array isn't named `/albums/a_great_big_world_-_is_there_anybody_out_there`, it's `/Albums/A Great Big World - Is There Anybody Out There`. Any way to easily fix that, or am I better of rewriting the array is created?

Comment: Uhm, yeah, there's no obvious way how to transform a lower-cased underscored string into a cased string. If you *do* have an obvious way, go for it. Or if you have a generator that turns the cased, spaced string into the lower-cased underscored string, use that the other way around. But sticking to identical, unique ids is always the better choice than trying to match two things which don't match. Rewrite your array.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll use the `formatURL` function in my main post the other way around. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @deceze this comment is off topic, but I have been trying to help a guy with a character encoding issue, which I know that you know a lot about. I can't solve his problem. Would you mind taking a look if you have a minute please? The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405588