# Broken Cyrillic file name when uploading to server

Tags: php, image, upload, cyrillic

[image]I have this php function:

```
function upload_file($f,$fn){
switch($f['type']){
case 'image/jpeg':$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($f['tmp_name']);break;
case 'image/png':case 'image/x-png':move_uploaded_file($f['tmp_name'],'../images/pc/'.$fn.'.png');break;
case 'image/pjpeg':$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($f['tmp_name']);break;
echo $f['type'],'<br />';
}
if(!empty($image)) imagejpeg($image,'../images/pc/'.$fn.'.png');
}
```

where $fn = "нова-категория" 
but when I upload the renamed file to server - the image name is broken and looks like this: 
РЅРѕРІР°-РєР°С‚РµРіРѕСЂРёСЏ.png

The interesting thing is that if I try to visit the image on server: site.com/images/pc/нова-категория.png => I can see the image.. 
Can you give me an idea what brakes the image name to look normal?

Comment: Hey, I am deleting my answer because it does not solve your problem and a post with no answers will get more visibility.  I am still monitoring the thread and as long as you notify me with `@Matt` I'll continue to try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you browse ftp with ftp client you see ANSI-encoded names (single-byte encodings). In this case `РЅРѕРІР°-РєР°С‚РµРіРѕСЂРёСЏ.png` is actually UTF-8 (double-byte) encoded `нова-категория.png`
2. When you upload file to web server, browser convert non unicode symbols in file name to UTF-8 (`нова-категория.png` becomes `РЅРѕРІР°-РєР°С‚РµРіРѕСЂРёСЏ.png`)
3. When you request `site.com/images/pc/нова-категория.png` browser again convert non unicode symbols to UTF-8 and server actually looks for `РЅРѕРІР°-РєР°С‚РµРіРѕСЂРёСЏ.png` (in ASCI-encoding).

So if you want to see "normal" names in ftp-client, you should convert them to your native encoding

```
function upload_file($f,$fn){
$fn=iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1251",$fn);
switch($f['type']){
...
```

But in this case you'll have problems with URLs to your files.
To write correct URL to ANSI-encoded names you should use this php code:

```
echo "site.com/images/pc/".rawurlencode("нова-категория.txt");
```

The way you should handle file names is depends on your use of that files.
But I don't recommend you to convert them. If you have problem, I thinks its not in "broken" names.