# Dynamic multidimensional array keys for class property

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to create multidimensional array with its keys defined in array? Yes, it is, according to bunch of Stack Overflow answers. Here is one: [Dynamic array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508352/dynamic-array-keys)

```
function insert_using_keys($arr, array $path, $value) { // See linked answer }
$arr = create_multi_array($arr, array('a', 'b', 'c'), 'yay'));
print_r($arr);
```

Prints

```
Array ( [a] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [c] => yay ) ) )
```

Would the same be possible for class properties?

This is a barebone version of my Collection class. Method `set_at` should add a multidimensional array to `$data` property the same way `insert_using_keys` function does.

```
class A {

    protected $data = array();

    public function set($key, $value) {
         $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function set_at(array $keys, $value) {

    }

}
```

I've tried a several modifications of the `insert_using_keys` to no avail. I was able to set the keys to the property, but not assign value "to the last one".

Would someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your example code that 'almost worked'?

Comment: @Stefan: The code did not "almost work". I was just able to set keys recursively. If you think that would help the question, I can recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the midst of recreating the "key-setter" function, I was able to answer my own question (was it your intention all along, Stefan?).

Here is the code:

```
public function set_at(array $keys, $value) {

    $first_key = array_shift($keys);

    foreach (array_reverse($keys) as $key) {
        $value = array($key => $value);
    }

    $this->data[$first_key] = $value;

}
```