# Convert a string into an associative array key?

Tags: php, arrays

Given a string that contains values separated by dots:

```
property.entry.item
```

What is the best way to convert that to a key for an associative array?

```
$result['imported_data']['property']['entry']['item']
```

The string may be of any length, with any number of dots and contain an value:

```
people.arizona.phoenix.smith
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
//found a dot, means we are expecting output from a previous function
if( preg_match('[.]',$value)) {

    //check for previous function output
    if(!is_null($result['import'])) {

        $chained_result_array = explode('.',$value);

        //make sure we have an array to work with
        if(is_array($chained_result_array)) {

            $array_key = '';
            foreach($chained_result_array as $key) {

                $array_key .= '[\''.$key.'\']';
            }

        }
        die(print_r(${result.'[\'import\']'.$array_key}));
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could convert the string to a variable variable, but I get an array to string conversion error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode the string into an array and loop through the array. ([DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51ee545b9fa16882f265aca34abaab383a0242d6))

```
/**
 * This is a test array
 */
$testArray['property']['entry']['item'] = 'Hello World';

/**
 * This is the path
 */
$string = 'property.entry.item';

/**
 * This is the function
 */
$array = explode('.', $string);

foreach($array as $i){
    if(!isset($tmp)){
        $tmp = &$testArray[$i];
    } else {
        $tmp = $tmp[$i];
    }
}

var_dump( $tmp ); // output = Hello World
```

Comment: I am not looking to get the values of the string, I am looking to use the values of the string as a key for another array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Snap, and a bit quicker than me, @sterling you are misreading his code - this does just what you want - see the live example in my answer for proof - this is essentially the same technique

Comment: @sterling Check the updated answer, it's in a bit more detail now

Comment: Made it a bit more cleaner by setting a pointer to `$testArray`

Comment: Thank you, I see now. I am trying to understand the implication of the reference variable. Also, how would you approach this if you had to prefix each final array with $result['import'] ?

Comment: If you know for sure it's _always_ import. You can do this like: `$array = explode('.', 'import'.$string);` or like this: `$tmp = &$testArray['import'][$i];` (just replace in above code).

Comment: Yeah, the problem I am having is that I will always need to be accessing the final array that starts with "$result['import']" so I can't wrap my head around how I access that $result portion.

Comment: Ahh I just looked up and put it together. $result would equal $testArray in your example.

Comment: Yes sir, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into parts, and itterate the array, accessing each element in turn:

```
function arrayDotNotation($array, $dotString){
    foreach(explode('.', $dotString) as $section){
        $array = $array[$section];
    }
    return $array;
}

$array = ['one'=>['two'=>['three'=>'hello']]];
$string = 'one.two.three';
echo arrayDotNotation($array, $string); //outputs hello
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vu8Hhy

Answer (score 1):

You should really check to see if keys exist before you reference them.  Otherwise, you're going to spew a lot of warnings.

```
function getProp($array, $propname) {   
    foreach(explode('.', $propname) as $node) {
        if(isset($array[$node]))
            $array = &$array[$node];
        else
            return null;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
$x = array(
    'name' => array(
        'first' => 'Joe',
        'last' => 'Bloe',
    ),
    'age' => 27,
    'employer' => array(
        'current' => array(
            'name' => 'Some Company',
        )
    )
);

assert(getProp($x, 'age') == 27);
assert(getProp($x, 'name.first') == 'Joe');
assert(getProp($x, 'employer.current.name') == 'Some Company');
assert(getProp($x, 'badthing') === NULL);
assert(getProp($x, 'address.zip') === NULL);
```

Or, if you are only interested in the `import` section of the tree:

```
getProp($x['import'], 'some.path');
```