# How to convert array into php multidimensional key values

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to convert an array to the key values of a separate array. For example:

```
$multi_key_list = [ 'ha','he','hi'];
$my_array = [ 
    'ha'=> [
        'he'=> [
            'hi'=> [ 
                'value to find'
            ]
        ],
    ],
];

echo $my_array[ some_function( $multi_key_list)  ] // 'value to find'
```

It seems like it could be done via a foreach loop but surely there must be a better way.

Comment: Please define *better*?

Comment: As in foreach doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009699/convert-a-string-into-an-associative-array-key

Comment: Not something like that... exactly that. knowing the correct terminology would have probably helped, huh?

Comment: It's difficult to know how to phrase some of these things, but at least you got there.